# What happens to an installed Chrome extension if you publish an update with a changed default keyboard shortcut in the manifest file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts, manifest.json

I've published a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) that has some default keyboard shortcuts specified in the `manifest.json` file.  I've changed my mind about what the defaults should be, and would like to change them for new installs going forward.

But what happens to those users who've already installed it?

1. If the user *hasn't* changed the defaults, will the new version of the extension change the shortcuts to the new defaults, thereby confusing the user?  (I'm hoping not.)
2. If the user *has* changed the defaults to something else, will the new version change them back?  (I'm assuming not.)

I could test this out by publishing a toy extension and then pushing an update, but I'm hoping someone out there may have already done the experiment.